# Dynamically adding inputs and bind validation in Parsley.js 2.0.0 rc3

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

In the new version of Parsley.js 2.0.0 rc3 how do you enable validation for dynamically added inputs?

Before I had destroyed the validation then re-initialized validation. However my understanding is you shouldn't have to do this in the new version, not sure if that is correct or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$("form").parsley().reset();`

Answer (score 0):

Well for now I have done the same thing as I did using version 1. After I add a new input I destroy and reset parsley on the form.

```
$("form").parsley().destroy();
$("form").parsley();
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#fieldId').parsley('addConstraint', {
                required: true 
            });